# How to print percentages outside the pie with python

Tags: python-3.x, series, pie-chart

I would like to have percentage values outside the pie. Maybe you can help

Here is my code :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

dict={'a':45, 'b': 123, 'c':2, 'd':1755, 'e':13}
ser = pd.Series(dict)

print(ser)

ser.plot(kind='pie', shadow=True, autopct='%1.2f%%')
plt.show()
```

As you can see in my case percentage values are not visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.pie.html) `pctdistance` controls the "ratio between the center of each pie slice and the start of the text generated by autopct", and it has a default value of `0.6`, which causes the percentage values to be inside the pie.

Try a `pctdistance` value `> 1`:

```py
>>> ser.plot(kind='pie', shadow=True, autopct='%1.2f%%', pctdistance=1.15)
```

(The above results in an "ugly" plot in which the percentages and the labels overlap. You can fix that by "moving" the labels using `labeldistance`.)